# TCP connection. How to make the client only send data at the moment of the server's read()?

Tags: c, ios, sockets, networking

I have a client in iPod iOS 4.3 and a server in Linux C. I can make a TCP connection and transfer data.

The server runs in a cycle with read() and printf.The client should send data only when asked. 
I found out that even after one read(), printf and halting at a getchar(), the client (iPod) is still getting the messagem *NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable* and sends the data.

After i press any key on the server, it gets to the read() again, and shows much more data.
I just wanted some help about the synchronous/asynchronous and blocking/non-blocking setting i should use in both the client and server. (theoretical, thus no need for coding, i guess.)

As requested, here is the server code:

```
void testApp::setup() {

int portno;
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
socklen_t clilen;

connection = 0; //Still no connection

sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (sockfd < 0) error("ERROR opening socket");

bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));


portno = atoi("50000");
serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);
if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr,sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0)
      error("ERROR on binding");

listen(sockfd,5);

}

void testApp::update() {

int check = 0;
int n;
char buffer[256];

if(connection != 0)
{
check = recv(newsockfd, buffer, 256, MSG_PEEK|MSG_DONTWAIT);
}
/*
developerweb.net/viewtopic.php?id=5627
*/
if(connection == 0 /*1st connection*/ | check == 0 | (check < 0 && errno != EAGAIN))
{ printf("CHECK é %d",check);
    if(connection != 0)
    {   close(newsockfd); newsockfd = -1; printf("Client disconnected.\n");}
    printf("\n\n-=Waiting for connection...=-\n");
    newsockfd = accept(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr,&clilen);
    printf("\nClient connected successfuly! \n");

}
if (newsockfd < 0) {printf("ERROR on accept"); close(newsockfd); newsockfd=-1; }
else if(newsockfd == 0) printf("No socket\n");
else
{
    printf("Waiting for message...\n");
    connection = 1;
    bzero(buffer,256);
    n = read(newsockfd,buffer,255);
    if (n < 0) error("ERROR reading from socket");
    printf("Here is the message: %s\n",buffer);
}

printf("\nPress any key to continue...");
getchar();
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: what does your server code look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry about coordinating between client and server -- that would require sending data back and forth, which would presumably require more coordinating... It becomes a circular problem. Just have the client send it's data and have the server read until there's no more data. The lower level networking software will queue up any data that comes in between reads, so you won't miss anything.

Comment: Thks for the answer, the problem is that i want to send the actual value of a slider to the server. But the way is working, the iPod gets really slow due to all this data transfer. So just for testing, i wanted to follow all the steps during the cycle (thus the getchar). I just want to get the actual value of the slider, the moment i want to read. i don't want anything else running on the background.

Comment: In that case you'll want to have the server send some sort of message to the client asking for another set of data. The client can't know when the server is or isn't reading data unless the server tells it.

Comment: well.. from my understanding of it, the iOS actually has something that tells the program that the server is listening:
    `-(void)stream:handleEvent:` 
with the event
    `NSStreamEventHasSpaceAvailable`. But yes, @Caleb, i thought about it yesterday, and with the getchar() it should work well. With the loop running (without the getchar()), i don't think it will make that much of a difference..

Comment: Right, but the connection is surely buffered on both ends: when you write data to the output stream on the client, that data is copied to a buffer where it waits to be sent. When the data is received on the server, it's again stored in a buffer until your program reads it. That's why you're getting all that data when you read data after the server has paused waiting for a key. If you don't want all that intermediate data, you should have the server signal the client that it wants another reading of your slider value.

Comment: Totally right, Caleb :) im gonna edit your answer with the server added code and the iPod part used for it. thks a lot!

Comment: hum.. i added an edit to your answer, why is not showing? :\ **edited:** _"Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed."_ -_-

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible for the client to know if the server is ready to read unless the server informs the client of that.

Instead of pushing out messages from the client, wait for a request from the server.